# Drupal 8 - Change position of the Save Preview Button in a form

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-8, content-type

I'm using Drupal version 8.6.10 with the default Bartik theme.

I created a new content type called Post and I would the change position of the "Save" and "Preview" buttons of the form used when creating a new Post.

Actually these buttons are shown immediately after the Title as you can see in the following picture:
[image]

Instead I want them to be shown at the **end** of the form.

These are the Post manage display settings:
[image]

I don't understand why this doesn't happen with the default content types provided by drupal (Article and Basic Page) but only with the content types I add.

How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably disabled the title position at some point and then re-enabled it without consideration for the position. The 'Manage display' setting you mentioned does not handle the positioning of the form element, it is meant for when you view content in read mode.

To resolve this, go to the 'Manage form display' tab of the specific content type and re-order the position of the title field (e.g. at the top of the field list).